# Getting Error While running manage.py ...import Error cannot import name backend

Tags: python, django

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py",                                                                                         line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry                                                                                        .py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.p                                                                                        y", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djorm_pgtrgm/__init_                                                                                        _.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import backend
ImportError: cannot import name backend
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using [`djorm_pgtrgm`](https://github.com/jleivaizq/djorm-ext-pgtrgm). It hasn't been updated for two years, so you can't expect it to work with recent versions of Django.

[This merged pull request](https://github.com/jleivaizq/djorm-ext-pgtrgm/pull/17/files) suggests that the import error has been fixed in the GitHub repo, but there hasn't been a release since then. You could try installing from source, but you should think about whether you want to use an unmaintained package in your project.

Comment: So is there any other option available to solve this issue?

Comment: Since `djorm-pgtrgm` isn't compatible with recent versions of Django, you can either stop using it in your project, try to install a version that is compatible with Django (you might have to write that yourself if it doesn't exist), or install an old, version of Django that is compatible with the app (I don't recommend that, it would be insecure). I'm not sure what other option you expect there to be.